# How can I access Internet using my PC through an Android phone connected via USB?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, networking, internet, tethering

I have a phone with Android 2.2 (HD2 with CM6.0) enabled to surf internet pages (data connection). Now, I would like to "surf" using my PC connected via USB to the phone.

Is it possible? Which programs do I need both on PC and Android?

If there are multiple solutions available, a free or low cost one is preferred

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here what do you mean by "enabled to navigate"? Are you trying to use your Android as a tethered GPS device for a PC, or something else? Are you expecting the maps and driving directions from the Navigate part of Google Maps to appear on your PC?

Comment: Sorry for the poor explanation. I mean to surf internet web pages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seeing that you have 2.2, the easiest solution would be to go to Settings -> Wireless & networks -> Tethering & portable hotspots. There you have an option to enable usb tethering (exactly what you asked for) or, even better try out Portable Wi-fi hotspot. That way you will be able to connect to the internet without connecting the phone via usb, and connect multiple devices if you want.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds as though you are just asking for a tethering solution (whereby you share your data connection on your phone with your pc). A stalwart in tethering is the app PDAnet. The free version (which doesn't allow secure connections, but allows most browsing and even WoW connection) can be downloaded from the market and installed on your phone. From there you install a client side program on your desktop/laptop, enable USB debugging on the phone, and follow PDAnet's instructions.

If you want to one-up my suggestion feel free, there are better solutions, but I would recommend trying the baseline to get your feet wet first. Especially considering you'll want to keep the data usage inconspicuous.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to use your Android phone as a GPS device for your PC (or presumably laptop) then you can try an app called [GPS Tether](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-gpstether-xAzq.aspx) this sets your phone up so that it will forward GPS details to a PC, but the PC does need the full Android Developer tools installed, so that it can use ADB (Android Debug Bridge) so isn't very straightforward.

This will only pass on the GPS location data to the PC, the PC will need to do everything else, so you'll need a separate navigation and/or maps program on the PC to make use of the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to connect to the files on your PC (which clearly is what you meant by navigate) you'll either need to share files on your PC, on the same home network you connect your phone to, or get an app like pocketpc to have a remote user connection to your phone.

Comment: Do you have a link to that app you mention?